# Notation for the operator that transforms sets (unordered) into tuples (ordered)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, vectors

Take a set $\mathcal{A}\equiv \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ of real numbers.

Is there any specific notation in math for the "operator" that transforms $\mathcal{A}$ into the 3-tuple (ordered)
$$
(a_1,a_2,a_3)
$$
?

Comment: The operation isn't clear.  if the original set is unordered we have $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}=\{a_3,a_1,a_2\}$ so would the image of your operation be $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ or $(a_3,a_1,a_2)$?

Comment: @lulu Thanks. What I want to formally say is the following: I start my discussion with a set $\mathcal{A}\equiv \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$. Then I want to tell the reader to fix any ordering of $\mathcal{A}$ and perform some operations with the resulting tuple.

Comment: How can do that formally?

Comment: I think the way you said it is clear.   With finite sets there is no problem with choosing.  I think it's always worth making it clear that a choice is involved, even if you are indifferent to the choice being made.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851667/converting-a-set-to-a-tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming for this function you want to find, you'd sometimes want a sequence with repeated elements. If this is the case, then the answer to you question is no.

**Example:**

If there was such a function that did this, say, $f$, then since $\{5\} = \{5,5\}$, you'll have

$f(\{5\}) = (5)$

and

$f(\{5,5\}) = (5,5)$

which doesn't make $f$ a function.